# Weird sound issue on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, gaming, speakers

I have a MSI GL62MVR (gtx1060, 8gb ram, i7 7gen) laptop with windows 10 (18362.295) and from time to time weird sound related problem occures. For instance recently I have installed battlefield 1 and had no sound at all, but after some debugging I have discovered that when I connect my bluetooth speaker to my laptop sound works normally. The game does appear in sound mixer but there is no signal coming when using built in speakers or aux headphones, only if the bluetooth speaker is selected sound works normally.

What I have tried:
 - uninstalled nahimic
 - reinstalled realtek drivers
 - changed default playback and communication devices
 - verified the game files (although it happens in some other games too)
 - reboot
 - updated windows
 - disabled origin in game overlay

I suppose it is some driver related issue but I have no idea what else can I do. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check per-app output settings are correct? - guide here - https://www.howtogeek.com/352787/how-to-set-per-app-sound-outputs-in-windows-10/

Comment: Problem disappeared randomly, but thanks for your help anyway.